# Histograma Python Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, histograma

Olá, gostaria de definir um histograma de uma função que criei para detectar uma região de imagem.

A função é essa.

```
def points (imagem, pontosFaciais):
p68 =[[47, 35, False],
      [35, 12, False],
      [12, 13, False],
      [13, 14, False],
      [14, 47, False],
      [41, 31, False], #buchecha esquerda
      [31, 4, False],
      [4, 3, False],
      [3, 2, False],
      [2, 41, False]]
for k in range(0, len(p68)):
    pontos = []
    ponto = [pontosFaciais.part(p68[k][0]).x, pontosFaciais.part(p68[k][0]).y]

    pontos.append(ponto)

    ponto = [pontosFaciais.part(p68[k][1]).x, pontosFaciais.part(p68[k][1]).y]

    pontos.append(ponto)

    pontos = np.array(pontos, dtype=np.int32)

    cv2.polylines(imagem, [pontos], p68[k][2], (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

E fiz isso para imprimir o histograma

```
red = cv2.calcHist([imagem], [2], points(), [256], [0, 256])
```

Mas não imprimi, como faço um histograma apenas da função acima ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Função calcHist

Você está utilizando a função [calcHist](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d) que possui estes parâmetros de entrada:

`cv2.calcHist(images, channels, mask, histSize, ranges[, hist[, accumulate]])`

1. `images` : é a imagem fonte de tipo uint8 ou float32. Deve ser passada entre colchetes ,ex.: `[img]`.
2. `channels` : Também é passada entre colchetes. É o index do canal em que o histograma é calculado. Por exemplo, se uma entrada é em escala de cinza, este valor é [0]. Para uma imagem colorida, `[0]`, `[1]` ou `[2]` pode ser passado para calcular o histograma de azul, verde ou vermelho (BGR) respectivamente.
3. `mask` : máscara de imagem. Para encontrar o histograma da imagem inteira, este é passado como `None`. Mas se desejar encontrar o histograma de uma região particular da imagem, a máscara de imagem deve ser criada e passada como parâmetro `mask`.
4. `histSize` : representa a contagem BIN. Precisa ser passada entre colchetes. Para escala completa, `[256]` é passado.
5. `ranges` : Este é o intervalo do histograma. Normalmente é passado `[0,256]`, ou seja, a escala completa.

Portanto, `red` no seu código, é um vetor 256x1, que possui os seguintes parâmetros:

`red = cv2.calcHist([imagem], [2], points(), [256], [0, 256])`

Então você deve estar utilizando uma imagem colorida. Para carregar uma imagem colorida com `imread` a flag `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` ou `-1` deve ser utilizada:

`imagem = cv2.imread('caminho\\para\\imagem_exemplo.jpg',-1)`

ou deixar em branco para a função "descobrir" o tipo de imagem:

`imagem = cv2.imread('caminho\\para\\imagem_exemplo.jpg')`

Com `[2]` o canal (BGR) de cor vermelha será extraído.

Com `[256]` e `[0,256]` as escalas completas de histSize e do intervalo são passadas.

E a máscara é passada com a função `points()`, porém sem nenhum parâmetro de entrada na função ela não está fazendo nada.

No parâmetro `mask` uma matriz 8-bit (CV_8U) de mesmo tamanho da imagem deve ser passada.

## Exemplo

Utilizando esta imagem:

[image: Logo SOpt]

#### Código

Comentários no código

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Carrega a imagem com seus dados de altura, largura e canais
# Cria a tupla colors (BGR) e cria a lista features
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\SOpt.png',-1)
height, width, channels = img.shape
colors = ('b', 'g', 'r')
features=[]

#Cria a máscara
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
mask[int(height*0.1):int(height*0.9), 0:int(width*0.6)] = 255
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)

#Mostra a imagem original, a máscara e a imagem com adição da máscara
plt.subplot(221), plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(222), plt.imshow(mask, 'gray')
plt.subplot(223), plt.imshow(masked_img)
plt.show()

#Exemplo PYImageSearch
#Carrega o Histograma da imagem inteira
chans = cv2.split(img)
for (chan, color) in zip(chans, colors):
    hist_full = cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    features.extend(hist_full)
    plt.plot(hist_full, color=color)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.show()

#Exemplo Doc OpenCV
#Carrega a imagem com a adição da máscara
for i,col in enumerate(colors):
    hist_mask = cv2.calcHist([img], [i], mask, [256], [0, 256])
    plt.plot(hist_mask, color=col)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.show()
```

**Referências:**

[Histograms - 1 : Find, Plot, Analyze !!!](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html)

[Clever Girl: A Guide to Utilizing Color Histograms for Computer Vision and Image Search Engines](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/22/clever-girl-a-guide-to-utilizing-color-histograms-for-computer-vision-and-image-search-engines/)